# Mapping Between Circular Types in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, recursion, types, mapping, cycle

This question is regarding statically inferring the signature of runtime types (seen in libraries such as [zod](https://github.com/vriad/zod) and [io-ts](https://github.com/gcanti/io-ts)).

The following example can be seen in action at [this TS playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAKgngB2FA3gKClAQgexwG2AEMQoBeKAIlwOJEoBoMoBJEAF3KrfceYBkAlgGdOFSkNF9MAVRCCcpcXIX0mAXzRpBHYACcAZkQDGyAMI4AJsGMAeGFGAAPdqEvDYiYAD5Uzdl4AXLAA3GiaaMb4RMIeNIQkFtbGUIIQCIQQoOweSTb2XgB08XS+6JgBSFzwSMV4CaQxUMaKomERUTEePHkpaRnAWRy5Vvk1wIU8Zf5e1UU8UE0tIG3hWp2xUCqKvbZmji5uI8kFSN6+-ZnZx2NF2yDTFbMU44X3ix7Lq5hf7HpgxnYOD0AAoEGAAEb4QQpHAGYJmADaAF0AJSoTQdaKbSTsXb7ZyuEDuKC7cbnVLpK7DUmjOyvXGPKCVZAvIq4j7NVrsMI-bn-QHAsGQ6Gw+Gk9EoTFaFlQAAiNlGewORJJZK8FLIzAA9NrUgZUuwAOQeIhQaGiZgEw7Ejy4-F004+Xy6xbEqAAd2QxhIqRABn0noAFkROIJjabzSJOHDmJgAPyklVHKD2x06AN6KAAeRdepIlmZQeQwGpOUWemQcOZsxayTjmCgiezydttJO5KgrsrxjAemEyCBUAA5sBOL6iHo9EQ4FBq+xi44yyDhEb0SyG42m-LFdZbLmUZvG8EQMAAG76I8n8+B12CA3hk2LKBgeSKBsI1sk+4OjsavNuoWXrNL6GaBh6IZhhGz6vqoc4GA2ibWqqHg-um-qBjIAEFoaT5mrBijwVyyTCEeiYyF+Nz0hqXZ6j2fYDsyOBQJW7B9qQC6hjWVQghBMJBp6gj4PgUAQsgYFTsAhZNAuyAESAqJHgmO51sAthYUpUDXheehXlAp46bR+q4ZGEL1HQxE2B+SaEimJSJHSRmsexRbIGZtC+huW6Ju5DRGfeJlumGuijlmqnGNZyEpj0jndmOLmyfpkBiVmXmNom4AQCl1kGfoYRAA).

Let's say we're trying to model some type information for runtime use. We can declare the following `Type` enum to get us started:

```
enum Type {
  Boolean = "Boolean",
  Int = "Int",
  List = "List",
  Union = "Union",
}
```

Our runtime type system should support booleans, integers, unions, and lists.

The base type looks like this:

```
interface Codec<T extends Type> {
  type: T;
}
```

The boolean and integer types use that base type like so.

Boolean:

```
class BooleanCodec implements Codec<Type.Boolean> {
  type = Type.Boolean as const;
}
```

Integer:

```
class IntCodec implements Codec<Type.Int> {
  type = Type.Int as const;
}
```

The union type accepts an array of types to unite:

```
class UnionCodec<C extends Codec<Type>> implements Codec<Type.Union> {
  type = Type.Union as const;
  constructor(public of: C[]) {}
}
```

And the list type accepts the type of which its elements are comprised:

```
class ListCodec<C extends Codec<Type>> implements Codec<Type.List> {
  type = Type.List as const;
  constructor(public of: C) {}
}
```

Let's construct a list of booleans or integers:

```
const listOfBooleanOrIntCodec = new ListCodec(
  new UnionCodec([
    new BooleanCodec(),
    new IntCodec(),
  ]),
);
```

This evaluates to the following object:

```
{
  type: Type.List,
  of: {
    type: Type.Union,
    of: [
      {
        type: Type.Boolean,
      },
      {
        type: Type.Int,
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

This codec would carry a signature of `ListCodec<UnionCodec<BooleanCodec | IntCodec>>`.

We might even see cycles within a given codec, and as such, mapping the type signature gets tricky. How would we get from the above to `(boolean | number)[]`? And does it account for deep nesting of codecs?

For `BooleanCodec` or `IntCodec`, working backwards is fairly easy... but the `UnionCodec` and `ListCodec` decoding needs to be recursive. I tried the following:

```
type Decode<C extends Codec<Type>> =
  // if it's a list
  C extends ListCodec<Codec<Type>>
    ? // and we can infer what it's a list of
      C extends ListCodec<infer O>
      ? // and the elements are of type codec
        O extends Codec<Type>
        ? // recurse to get an array of the element(s') type
          Decode<O>[]
        : never
      : never
    : // if it's a union
    C extends UnionCodec<Codec<Type>>
    // and we can infer what it's a union of
    ? C extends UnionCodec<infer U>
      // and it's a union of codecs
      ? U extends Codec<Type>
        // recurse to return that type (which will be inferred as the union)
        ? Decode<U>
        : never
      : never
      // if it's a boolean codec
    : C extends BooleanCodec
    // return the boolean type
    ? boolean
    // if it's ant integer codec
    : C extends IntCodec
    // return the number type
    ? number
    : never;
```

It regrettably errors with `Type alias 'Decode' circularly references itself` and `Type 'Decode' is not generic`.

I'm wondering if it's possible to accomplish this kind of cyclical type-mapping, and how I might make such a utility as `Decode` work? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually define types and then derive a generic codec from it, rather than constructing codecs explicitly.

For example: First, define your types with some data and encode their relationships (list item and union values):

```
type Type = Integer | List<any> | Union<any>;
interface Integer {
  type: 'integer';
}
interface List<T extends Type> {
  type: 'list';
  item: T;
}
type UnionValues = Type[];
interface Union<T extends UnionValues> {
  type: 'union';
  values: T;
}
```

It's nice to also provide helpers for creating these types:

```
const integer: Integer = { type: 'integer' };
const list = <T extends Type>(item: T): List<T> => ({
  type: 'list',
  item
});
const union = <T extends UnionValues>(...values: T): Union<T> => ({
  type: 'union',
  values
});
```

You can then write a recursive type-mapping function. This will map a `Type` to its corresponding JS type:

```
type Decode<T> =
  // terminal recursion: Integer is represented as a number
  T extends Integer ? number :
  // extract the Item from the list and construct an Array recursively
  T extends List<infer I> ? Decode<I>[] :
  // union is an array of types, so loop through and decode them
  T extends Union<infer U> ? {
    [i in Extract<keyof U, number>]: Decode<U[i]>;
  }[[Extract<keyof U, number>]] :
  never
  ;
```

Define your codec as a read from `Type => Value`:

```
interface Codec<T extends Type, V> {
  type: T;
  read(value: any): V;
}
```

Write a function that maps a type instance to its Codec:

```
function codec<T extends Type>(type: T): Codec<T, Decode<T>> {
  // todo
}
```

Now you can safely map between your type system and JS types:

```
const i = codec(integer);
const number: number = i.read('1');

const l = codec(list(integer));
const numberArray: number[] = l.read('[1, 2]');

const u = codec(union(integer, list(integer)));
const numberOrArrayOfNumbers: number | number[] = u.read('1');
```

I tried to recreate your example where developers write codecs which encode their type. I think this is loosely what you're trying to do. It was a bit more complicated because you need to map over tuples.

Integer codec is a straight mapping of Integer -> number.

```
class IntegerCodec implements Codec<Integer, number> {
  public readonly type: Integer = integer;

  public read(value: any): number {
    return parseInt(value, 10);
  }
}
```

ListCodec recursively computes a mapping of List -> ItemValue[]

```
namespace Codec {
  // helper type function for grabbing the JS type from a Codec<any, any>
  export type GetValue<C extends Codec<any, any>> = C extends Codec<any, infer V> ? V : never;
}
// this is where we recurse and compute the Type and JSType from the provided Item codec
class ListCodec<Item extends Codec<any, any>> implements Codec<List<Item['type']>, Codec.GetValue<Item>[]> {
  public readonly type: List<Item['type']>;
  constructor(public readonly item: Item)  {
    this.type = list(item.type);
  }

  public read(value: any): Codec.GetValue<Item>[] {
    return value.map((v: any) => this.item.read(v));
  }
}
```

Union is a bit more difficult because we need to map over a tuple of codecs to compute types and values.

First utility: Compute the Union Type from tuple of Codecs

```
type ComputeUnionType<V extends Codec<any, any>[]> = Union<Type[] & {
  [i in Extract<keyof V, number>]: V[i]['type']
}>;
```

Second utility: Compute the Union JS Type from a Tuple of Codecs:

```
type ComputeUnionValue<V extends Codec<any, any>[]> = {
  [i in Extract<keyof V, number>]: Codec.GetValue<V[i]>;
}[Extract<keyof V, number>];
```

Then we write a UnionCodec which recursively computes the Type and JS Type of a Union:

```
class UnionCodec<V extends Codec<any, any>[]> implements Codec<
  ComputeUnionType<V>,
  ComputeUnionValue<V>
> {
  public readonly type: ComputeUnionType<V>;

  constructor(public readonly codecs: V) {}
  public read(value: any): ComputeUnionValue<V> {
    throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
  }
}
```

Now your example type-checks:

```
const ic = new IntegerCodec();
const lc: ListCodec<IntegerCodec> = new ListCodec(new IntegerCodec());
const uc: UnionCodec<[ListCodec<IntegerCodec>, IntegerCodec]> = new UnionCodec([lc, ic]);

const listValue: number | number[] = uc.read('1');
```

Comment: –– I've confirmed this solution works perfectly! Thank you!